# Losing my reputations day by day

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Yesterday I have lost 15 reputations in Mathematics Stack Exchange. Today it is 35! I didn't delete any problem or any answer. There were no notifications, no messages. I don't know what to do for that :(

Is there any method to know how I have lost my reputations in Mathematics Stack Exchange ?

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: This question was deleted recently, including your answer, worth 20 points: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122671/negate-definition-of-limit

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks

Comment: You are [losing your religion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPxVm8663Zo)? :-P

Comment: (I guess 35 is likely, I was forgetting that it could be accepted, as this isn't shown on deleted questions.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfTDSFpvGxE

Comment: To make my point bit more concise: Even if the older question is about the same problem, if it contains outdated information, I would prefer not to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Martin's point about the "How did I lose rep?" question, but the "Where reputation disappears" question is an apt duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the  [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) of your profile, and check `show removed posts` at the bottom. This will likely indicate where the reputation was lost.